# Segmenting two contours into two different images of same size using openCV-python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have two contours in the first [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bRXg.jpg). I need to segment out individual contours and make two images out of it like this: [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bIre.jpg) and [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSOeM.jpg). The individual output image has to be of the same dimension as the input image. How can this be achieved using openCV-python ? My code for drawing contours:

```
    image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    # convert all coordinates floating point values to int
    box = np.int0(box)
    # draw a red 'nghien' rectangle
    cv2.drawContours(im, [box], 0, (0, 0, 255))
    cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (255, 255, 0), 1)
```

Comment: Look for connected component analysis or connected component labelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `cv2.drawContours` in wrong way. Passing the `-1` as contour index would draw all the contours and not the individual ones. To draw the individual contours you need to pass the corresponding index as:

```
_, cnt, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canvas.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in xrange(len(cnt)):
    output_canvas = np.zeros(canvas.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(output_canvas, cnt, i, np.array([255, 255, 255, 255]), -1)
    cv2.imwrite("./contour{}.png".format(i), output_canvas)
```

Comment: Works but only when i change "cv2.drawContours(output_canvas, cnt, i, np.array([255, 255, 255, 255]), -1)" to "cv2.drawContours(output_canvas, cnt, i, (255,255,255), -1). Thank you.